# Redistribution Loops and Route Tagging

Tags: ospf, eigrp, redistribution

I've read that when we configure multipoint redistribution, it's a good idea to tag our routes to prevent them from being advertised from Protocol 1 - Protocol 2 - Back to Protocol 1.

[image]

Source: NetworkLessons

However, in these tagging and redistribution loop examples, I always see one of the protocols being RIP specifically.

Let's assume for a second that the top domain is OSPF and the bottom one is RIP.

So if we are redistributing between RIP and OSPF. R1 originally learns about the 1.1.1.0/24 network using RIP and when it receives the redistributed route from R2, it will install the OSPF route into the RIB instead (because OSPF has a lower AD) and will redistribute it back into RIP.

RIP doesn't differentiate between an internal and an external route, so anything that was redistributed from it can be redistributed back to it and if the redistributed route happens to have a lower metric, RIP will gladly install the route, causing a potential loop.

But this cannot happen with OSPF or EIGRP, right? Both are capable of differentiating between internal and external routes. Take this example

[image]

A router will only redistribute a network if it has a valid entry for it in the RIB and the source protocol that redistributes into the destination protocol must be the source of the route.

So if the 1.1.1.0/24 OSPF network is redistributed into EIGRP by R1 and received by R2, R2 won't install that route into its RIB (due to the AD of 170) and won't redistribute it back into the OSPF domain because the received route (External EIGRP route) doesn't match the source protocol in the RIB.

So can these "loops" also occur with OSPF and EIGRP who are capable of differentiating between internal and external routes? If not, where exactly can this Route Tagging be used?

Thank you for your help.